# Angular strap binding datePicker not working with start and end date?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I use angular strap datePicker

```
<input type="text" name="dateFrom" ng-model="dateFrom" bs-datepicker                           
    data-end-date="{{endDate}}" data-start-date="{{startDate}}" />
```

How ever when change endDate or startDate from code it does update in the DOM but the date picker remains unaware of this change, is there some kind of update I need to trigger?

The change is done via a `ng-click` with function on the same scope, that then sets a new value for `endDate` and `startDate`.

Like so (CoffeeScript):

```
$scope.setDateRange = (dateRange) ->
    if dateRange is "past"
        $scope.endDate = "-1d"
        $scope.startDate = ""

     if dateRange is "now"
        $scope.endDate = ""
        $scope.startDate = ""

    if dateRange is "future"
        $scope.endDate = ""
        $scope.startDate = "+1d"
```

**Edit:**

Here is the solution:

On the controller constructor I store the date from and to controls:

```
dateFromCtrl = $element.find 'input[name="dateFrom"]'
dateToCtrl = $element.find 'input[name="dateTo"]'
```

Then when `setDateRange`is called I made few helper methods to call the `datepicker` `setEndDate` and `setStartDate` methods:

```
setEndDate = (date) ->
    dateFromCtrl.datepicker 'setEndDate', date
    dateToCtrl.datepicker 'setEndDate', date

setStartDate = (date) ->
    dateFromCtrl.datepicker 'setStartDate', date
    dateToCtrl.datepicker 'setStartDate', date

setDateRange = (dateRange) ->

    if dateRange is "past"
        setEndDate "-1d"
        setStartDate ""

     if dateRange is "now"
        setEndDate ""
        setStartDate ""

    if dateRange is "future"
        setEndDate ""
        setStartDate "+1d"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the setStartDate() and setEndDate() calls:

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setstartdate

Or you might look at the datepicker that is now provided by the Angular folks, so it has especially nice integration within Angular:  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/